# Simular el lanzamiento de un dado en PHP con rand(1,6)

Tags: php, random

Estoy simulando el lanzamiento de un dado usando la funcion rand(1,6) de PHP. Uso la siguiente function que es trivial:

```
function lanzarDado() {    
    $valor = rand (1,6);
    return $valor;
}
```

La uso en un juego que estoy desarrollando y en el que hay 2 contendientes que van lanzando el dado alternativamente. En una partida he ejecutado la function  70 veces y la distribución de resultados que han salido no terminar de ser uniforme. Entiendo que si rand(1,6) genera números aleatorios el porcentaje de veces que sale cada número del "dado" debería acercarse 16.6 % cosa que no me ha ocurrido.
Quería saber si alguien con experiencia en el uso de la funcion rand() ha notado algo similar usando dicha función? ¿O será que la muestra de 70 lanzamientos es muy pequeña?

Comment: Con qué código simulas el proceso? Qué datos que dices que no se distribuyen como dices? Las preguntas del tipo: "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento de SO y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Otra pregunta: qué versión de PHP estás usando? Desde 7.1.0, `rand()` es un alias para `mt_rand()` que parece comportarse mejor según [la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) y los comentarios en ella...

Comment: La versión de PHP es la 7.3.13. Revisaré la documentación que me comentas. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que la distribución uniforme de los pseudoaleatorios no va a verse tan rápido como esperas (con 70 datos). Incluso en teoremas como el de grandes números (para n>30, con suficientes muestras todo tiende a distribuirse normal), la muestra se ajusta a la distribución esperada cuando se tienen datos suficientes.

Usé tu código

```
<?php

function lanzarDado() {    
    $valor = rand (1,6);
    return $valor;
} 

for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++){
    print(strval(lanzarDado()) . " | $i <br/>");
}
?>
```

Y modifiqué la cantidad de veces que se iba ejecutando.

Para 100 ejecuciones del método, los datos se distribuían así (el porcentaje de cada uno es entero porque mapea uno a uno con la cantidad de ocurrencias):

```
#  % / Cant.
1    17
2    19
3    16
4    19
5    16
6    13
```

Para 1000 ejecuciones, los datos se ven así:

```
#     %     Cant.
1   16.2    162
2   16.7    167
3   16.4    164
4   17.6    176
5   15.8    158
6   17.3    173
```

Para 10000 ocurrencias:

```
#       %    Cant.
1    16.77   1677
2    16.67   1667
3    17.22   1722
4    16.29   1629
5    16.46   1646
6    16.59   1659
```

Como ves, a medida que hay más datos, la muestra se ajusta mejor a la distribución.

Si cambio el PRNG por `mt_rand()` (que ya no usa libc sino código propio de PHP), la cosa cambia un poco...

Primera ejecución de 10000:

```
#       %    Cant.
1   16.22   1622
2   16.56   1656
3   16.7    1670
4   16.88   1688
5   16.84   1684
6   16.8    1680
```

Segunda ejecución de 10000:

```
#       %    Cant.
1    16.27  1627
2    16.9   1690
3    16.92  1692
4    16.82  1682
5    16.61  1661
6    16.48  1648
```

Uno podría argumentar que la desviación de los datos respecto de la distribución sobre la que se están intentando generar es menor en promedio. Ese análisis tiene más sentido que simplemente decir que los datos no están exactamente el 16.6% en cada número, porque eso no es realista. Hay métodos para analizar esto pero no sé si estén dentro del alcance de la pregunta.

También podría revisarse si es posible mejorar el uso del algoritmo al proveer una semilla mejor para cada ejecución de `rand()` o `mt_rand()`, que fue un [tema de discusión](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/a0724d30817600540946b41e40f4cfc2a0c30f80) y terminó en que `mt_srand()` y `srand()` -los métodos que definen la semilla a usar por el generador de números pseudoaleatorios- [permiten](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-srand.php) elegir si se usa la versión "dañada" o la arreglada que puso la gente a pelear en aquel entonces.

También están al alcance los [comentarios en SO original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11358691/how-is-phps-mt-rand-seeded) sobre las críticas a estos métodos (que han mejorado pero no confiaría en que funcionen tan bien como quisiéramos).